# ggplot with two x variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot the Current_Prices and Test_Prices like `fill` in ggplot, but I cannot figure out the function to combine those two columns after running summarise in dplyr.

```
carrier%>%
  group_by(!!category) %>%
  summarise(Current_Prices = mean(original_percent_higher[original_percent_higher>0], na.rm = TRUE), 
            Test_Prices = mean(Percent_Higher[Percent_Higher>0], na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes_string(input$Category, "Current_Prices")) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(Current_Prices)), size = 3.2, vjust = -0.5, 
            position = position_dodge(width = 1), na.rm = TRUE)
```

What I would like to create between summarise and ggplot is something like:

```
Class Version Mean
a     current  1
a     test     2
b     current  3
b     test     4
```

So then I can run ggplot with Class as x, Mean as y, and Version as fill.

What I have right now after summarise is something like:

```
Class Current Test
a     1       2
b     3       4
c     5       6
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example of initial data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[DMR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52088201/3817004) points in the right direction but is incomplete as it has left out the plotting part.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
data.frame(Class = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
           Current = c(1, 3, 5),
           Test = c(2, 4, 6)) %>% 
  # reshape from wide to long format
  gather(Version, Mean_Price, -Class) %>%
  # here comes the plotting stuff 
  ggplot(aes(Class, Mean_Price, fill = Version)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(Mean_Price)), size = 3.2, vjust = -0.5,
            position = position_dodge(width = 1), na.rm = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the values are in 'wide' format, for ggplot you want them in 'long' format as you've stated. The following will convert the output of summarise you've described to the format you want. The creation of `data_wide` is just for illustration purposes for this example. You can of course also insert this into your existing statement using the pipe (%>%) operator:

```
library(tidyr)

data_wide <- data.frame(Class = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
                        Current = c(1, 3, 5),
                        Test = c(2, 4, 6))

data_long <- gather(data_wide, Version, Mean, Current:Test, factor_key=TRUE)
```